# mod() function in PGF/TikZ has strange behavior for negative values

Tags: tikz-pgf

It seems that the `mod()` function in PGF/TikZ has problems with negative values. The code

```
\draw [domain=-5:5, samples=100] plot (\x, {exp(mod(\x+1,2)-1)-1.5431});
```

will produce this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: There are two modulo functions `mod()` and `Mod()`. You are using the wrong one. See the manual for details

Answer (score 4):

TikZ has two modulo functions: `mod()` and `Mod()`. `Mod()` will handle correctly negative values.